# Builder (android.content.Context)' is not public in 'io.realm.RealmConfiguration.Builder'. Cannot be accessed from outside package

Tags: java, android, realm

And add the dependencies and plugins everything is fine but when I put this

```
 private void setUpRealmConfig(){


    RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext()).deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded().build();
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
}
```

in the part of = RealmConfiguration.Builder.  I get this error:

> Builder(android.content.Context)' is not public in 'io.realm.RealmConfiguration.Builder'. Cannot be accessed from outside package

and I do not know what to do.

Comment: cuz it should but `Realm.init(context); RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded().build();`

Answer (score 39):

If I'm not mistaken, since version 2 of Realm you need pass *context* to Ream by call `init()` method.

1. you need to call `init()` of Realm
2. you can build you realm configuration

---

```
private void setUpRealmConfig(){

    // initialize Realm
    Realm.init(getApplicationContext());

    // create your Realm configuration
    RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.
                                   Builder().
                                   deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded().
                                   build();
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

In Realm, we don't pass any parameter to Builder.To set Realm configuration setting we simply call Builder initialization.

For eg:-

```
    Realm.init(getApplicationContext());

    RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                .name(Realm.DEFAULT_REALM_NAME)
                .schemaVersion(0)
                .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                .build();
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that constructor is deprecated.  Try using this one instead:

```
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded().build();
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to set configuration of Realm, do the following in your Application.class

```
private void initRealm() {

    // initialize realm
    Realm.init(getApplicationContext());

    // create realm configuration
    RealmConfiguration defaultConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .schemaVersion(0)
            .migration(new RealmLocalMigration())
            .build();
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(defaultConfig);

}
```